# Button touch delegate not working

Tags: objective-c, ios7, delegates

I am having problems getting my delegated method in MainViewController.m to execute. When the Logout Button in MenuView.xib is pressed, it goes to the IBAction logoutButton in MenuView.m (this works). This call the logoutButton delegate function in LogoutDelegate. MainViewController.h takes in the LogoutDelegate and MainViewController.m defines the logoutButton method (very bottom of code).

What am I missing?

MenuView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol LogoutDelegate
    -(void)logoutButton;
@end

@interface MenuView : UIView
    @property (nonatomic, retain) id <LogoutDelegate> logoutDelegate;
    - (IBAction)logoutButton:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

MenuView.m

```
#import "MenuView.h"
#import "AlertStatus.h"

@implementation MenuView

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code
        }
        return self;
    }

-(IBAction) logoutButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"In the logoutButton IBAction method");
    [_logoutDelegate logoutButton];
}

@end
```

MainViewController.h (not whole file)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MenuView.h"


@interface MainViewController : UIViewController 
    <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, LogoutDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MenuView *menuView;

- (IBAction)menuButtonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

@end
```

MainViewController.m (not whole file)

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "AlertStatus.h"

@interface MainViewController ()
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    //Gather profiles and populate table after view loads
    [self gatherProfiles];    
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 - (IBAction)menuButtonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    //This is for the menu which is encapsulated in a transparent view
    if (self.menuView){
        [self.transView removeFromSuperview];
        self.menuView = Nil;
        self.transView = Nil;
    }
    else {

        //Create a transparent view that covers the whole window. This is made to
        //destroy the view when the users touches the outside of the menuView
        //that will be encapsulated in this.
        self.transView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.transView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        //Create menu view and encapsulate it in the transparent view
        self.menuView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        self.menuView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0f;
        self.menuView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
        self.menuView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        self.menuView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, self.menuView.frame.size.width,
                                     self.menuView.frame.size.height);
        [self.transView addSubview:self.menuView];

        //Create a UITapRecognizer and make sure that button touches are counted. Non button touches will
        //destroy the view as it was touched outside the menuView
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]     
            initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
        //singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        [self.transView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

        //Add the transparent view that encapsulated the menuView in the main view.
        [self.view addSubview: self.transView];
    }
}

//Removed Sub Views from MainView when tapped
-(void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    //This is for the menu which is encapsulated in a transparent view
    if(self.menuView) {
        [self.transView removeFromSuperview];
        self.menuView = Nil;
        self.transView = Nil;
    }
 }

//THIS IS A DELEGATED METHOD FROM THE MenuView
//When the logout button in MenuView is pressed this method will be called
- (void)logoutButton{
    NSLog(@"In the logoutButton method in MainViewController");
}


@end
```

Comment: Are you ever actually setting the `logoutDelegate` property?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. This is my first experience with delegates. I thought I set everything I needed to set, but obviously something is not right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set the delegate properly

```
 @implementation MainViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     [self.menuView setLogoutDelegate:self];
  }

  .....
  .....

  @end
```

Comment: I put this line in and no change. Do you see anything else wrong? This is my first experience with delegates. :)

Comment: so you get the log  `NSLog(@"In the logoutButton IBAction method");`"??? Also try adding [self.menuView setLogoutDelegate:self]; after the line `self.menuView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: I took it out of the viewDidLoad and put it here and it worked!!!! Thanks so much. 

Another question if you want to answer.....If I have another button in the menuView (modifyProfile), do I need to make a whole new delegate or can I use this one somehow?

Comment: Since both button is in the same view, update the protocol to include one more method to forward the second button click event.

Comment: I would say you in your case you only need one delegate. But it depends on what you want to achieve. I guess renaming your delegate to `MenuViewDelegate` and adding the second method to the protocol `-(void)secondButtonTouched` could be what you want.